Al tratar de iniciar sesión de una base de datos desde Flask con python y MySQL Workbench = mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)
No tengo problemas para conectar a la base de datos ni para registrar ususarios tampoco, el error me lo arroja al tratar de iniciar sesión con algún ususaro ya creado. He visto un detalle en MySQL Workbench que las columnas id, description, created_by, created_at, completed fueron creadas en la tabla "todo" y no en la tabla "user" pero no sé si ahí esté el error... Les comparto mi código y gracias de antemano por su valiosa ayuda al respecto...
El error que me arroja..
ProgrammingError
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't.created_by = u.id order by created_at desc' at line 1
auth.py
import functools
 
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session
)
 
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
 
from todo.db import get_db
 
bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')
 
@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db, c = get_db()
        error = None
        c.execute(
            'select id from user where username = %s', (username,)
        )
        if not username:
            error = 'Username es requerido'
        if not password:
            error = 'Username es requerido'
        elif c.fetchone() is not None:
            error = 'Usuario {} se encuentra registrado.'.format(username)
        
        if error is None:
            c.execute(
                'insert into user (username, password) values (%s, %s)',
                (username, generate_password_hash(password))
            )
            db.commit()
            
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        
        flash(error)
        
    return render_template('auth/register.html')
 
 
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db, c = get_db()
        error = None
        c.execute(
            'select * from user where username = %s', (username,)
        )
        user = c.fetchone()
        
        if user is None:
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña invalida'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña invalida'
        
        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('todo.index'))
        
        flash(error)
    
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
@bp.before_app_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')
    
    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        db, c = get_db()
        c.execute(
            'select * from user where id = %s', (user_id,) # Se coloca una ',' porque tiene 1 sólo parámetro.
        )
        g.user = c.fetchone() # Nos devolverá el 1er elemento que encuentre.
 
def login_required(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped_view(**kwars):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        
        return view(**kwars)
    return wrapped_view
 
@bp.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))      

init.py
import os

from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, abort, render_template

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='mikey',
        DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
        DATABASE=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE'),
    )

    from . import db
    
    # Inicializar la aplicación con los comandos personalizados
    db.init_app(app)
    
    from . import auth
    from . import todo
    
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
    app.register_blueprint(todo.bp)
    
    @app.route('/hola')
    def hola():
        return 'Hello Moto'
    
    return app

todo.py
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
from todo.auth import login_required # Para proteger los endpoints, el usuario tiene que iniciar sesión necesariamente
from todo.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('todo',__name__)# Buscamos en la base de datos todos los usuarios que haya creado.

@bp.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    db, c = get_db() # Buscamos en la base de datos todos los usuarios que haya creado.
    c.execute(
        'select t.id, t.description, u.username, t.completed, t.created_at from todo t JOIN user u t.created_by = u.id order by created_at desc'
    )
    todos = c.fetchall()
    
    return render_template('todo/index.html', todos=todos)

@bp.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create():
    return ''

@bp.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update():
    return ''

index.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
<h1>{% block title %}Todos{% endblock %}</h1>
{% if <g.user %}
    <a class="action" href="{{ url_for('todo.create') }}">Nuevo</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<ul>
{% for todo in todos %}
<li class="todo">
    <div>
        <h1>
            {% if todo['completed'] == 1 %}
            <strike>{{ todo['description'] }}</strike>
            {% else %}
            {{ todo['description'] }}
            {% endif %}

        </h1>
        <div class="about">{{ todo['created_at'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</div>
        <a class="action" href="{{ url_for('todo.update', id=todo['id']) }}">Editar</a>
    </div>
</li>
{% if not loop.last %}
<hr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endblock %}


db.py
import mysql.connector

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from .schema import instructions

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=current_app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
            user=current_app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
            password=current_app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            database=current_app.config['DATABASE']
        )
        g.c = g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db, c = get_db()
    for i in instructions:
        c.execute(i)
    db.commit()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Base de datos inicializada')

def init_app(app):
    if app is not None:
        app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
        app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)


Se te olvidó el ON en el JOIN: ... from todo t JOIN user u ON t.created_by = u.id ...

Muchísimas gracias!!! Solucionado!!!
